# Admob mediation /w chartboost, no impressions even though everything seems to work?

Tags: admob, chartboost, mobile-ad-mediation

I am trying to add Chartboost to my currently working setup with Admob (both rewarded video and interstitial). I have followed the documentation from Admob: https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/mediation/chartboost

I can see on the Admob report for mediation that the mediation group is working, I get network requests to Chartboost. But I do not get the SDK sticker over at Chartboost (indicating that the SDK is integrated). I could not get this to work until I added the lines of code that you should use if you are using Chartboost as a standalone service:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Chartboost.startWithAppId(this, appId, appSignature);
    Chartboost.onCreate(this);
    }   
}
```

Now I got the SDK sticker, but I read that you should not do it that way, Admob should handle it all under the hood, so I chaged it back.

I do not get any error messages at all. This is what I see in the log:

```
12-16 16:49:45.344 21656-21656/? I/Ads: Starting ad request.
12-16 16:49:45.344 21656-21656/? I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("B5E99B74D22121F11E46D7C4714806A0") to get test ads on this device.
12-16 16:49:45.364 21656-21706/? W/Ads: Invoke Firebase method getInstance error.
12-16 16:49:45.374 21656-21706/? W/Ads: The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date
12-16 16:49:45.384 21656-21656/? I/Ads: Starting ad request.
12-16 16:49:45.384 21656-21656/? I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("B5E99B74D22121F11E46D7C4714806A0") to get test ads on this device.
12-16 16:49:47.404 1548-21811/? W/Ads: App does not have the required permissions to get location
12-16 16:49:47.754 21656-21656/? W/Ads: Server parameters: {"gwhirl_share_location":"1","pubid":"ca-app-pub-xxx\/xxx\/cak=no_cache&cadc=lm&caqid=xxx"}
12-16 16:49:47.754 21656-21656/? W/Ads: Server parameters: {"gwhirl_share_location":"1","pubid":"ca-app-pub-xxx\/xxx\/cak=no_cache&cadc=lm&caqid=xxx"}
12-16 16:49:47.764 21656-21656/? I/Ads: Starting ad request.
12-16 16:49:47.764 21656-21656/? I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("B5E99B74D22121F11E46D7C4714806A0") to get test ads on this device.
12-16 16:49:48.174 21656-21921/? I/Ads: Trying mediation network: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/aclk?sa=L&ai=CUyxVnEA1WpziGY2B6gS04IKwAvnJ2qYF0e-FupIBABAIIILf4CZg8a38haQfqQIAAAAAgIQuQagDAaoEKk_Qz9GbpjZwuQkLYYaQ6CeGyH_RDbbSf2H8VjsxjAPreW2a9o02X10ACJAGAcAGC4AHgfipMJgHAdIIBwiMQxABGAI&num=1&cid=CAASBORo9I4&sig=AOD64_0lsBVscqSZ84s_pWXdpTQQwsp2Gw&adurl=http://example.com
12-16 16:49:48.184 21656-21656/? I/Ads: Instantiating mediation adapter: com.google.ads.mediation.chartboost.ChartboostAdapter
12-16 16:49:48.184 21656-21921/? I/Ads: Trying mediation network: 
12-16 16:49:48.184 21656-21656/? I/Ads: Instantiating mediation adapter: com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter
12-16 16:49:48.184 21656-21656/? W/Ads: Server parameters: {"gwhirl_share_location":"1","pubid":"ca-app-pub-xxx\/xxx\/cak=no_cache&cadc=lm&caqid=xxx"}
12-16 16:49:48.204 21656-21656/? I/Ads: Starting ad request.
12-16 16:49:48.204 21656-21656/? I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("B5E99B74D22121F11E46D7C4714806A0") to get test ads on this device.
12-16 16:49:51.744 21656-21656/? I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
12-16 16:49:51.744 21656-21656/? I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
12-16 16:49:51.754 21656-21656/? I/System.out: Ads: Succeeded to load video ad
12-16 16:49:52.474 21656-21656/? I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
12-16 16:49:52.484 21656-21656/? I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
```

I thought it was strange that I get no error message so I removed the adapter libraries (I keept the chartboost.jar but not the *.aar) to see if I would get any errors then but the log output was exactly the same. I am a bit confused and I have no idea if this is just going to start working once I go live and get real requests?

*EDIT*
I have now gone live and are getting real request from real user and I get a lot of "Network request" but no "Impression"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is prioritizing Chartboost over AdMob by manually setting a very high eCPM (click the pencil icon next to the network instance). This will result in forcing Chartboost to the top of the waterfall and you'll be able to ensure that ads are coming through. See the image below...

All you need to do is Turn off optimize and set the eCPM from $5 to something like $99.

[image: Turn off optimize and set the eCPM from $5 to something like $99]
Best,
Ed

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That was among the first things I tried. It was at that point I got: "I can see on the Admob report for mediation that the mediation group is working, I get network requests to Chartboost" It still did not show anything over at Chartboost, it still said that the SDK was not integrated..

Comment: Makes sense. Is there any functional benefit to having Chartboost show the sticker?

Comment: The sticker indicates that your app has made a request to Chartboost. So no sticker means it does not work. Since it is not working and I get no error messages I don't really know what to do.